Не могу перейти на старую версию Aiogram!
Использую команду pip install aiogram==2.25.1, выдаёт:
6 warnings and 5 errors generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for aiohttp
Failed to build aiohttp
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.2.1 -> 24.0
[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
(.venv) (base) zurab@MacBook-Air-Zurab pythonProject4 % 

что делать?

Приведите полный текст ошибки

Сделай pip install --upgrade pip в  терминале пайчарма
